# WebStorm Mac OS navigate back ignore cursor position

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Using WebStorm Build 2022.2.3 (#WS-222.4345.14, built on October 4, 2022), my Navigate Back shortcut (either keyboard ⌘[ *or* menu Navigate → Back), it seems as though the feature is working but ignoring the cursor position.

So, if I navigate back to a previously opened tab, WebStorm shows the previous tab, which seems fine.

But, if a step in the navigation moves to another position on the same page, it seems to be ignored. Nothing happens.

So, a series of Navigate Back steps result in a combination of working and not working, depending on whether the tab switches.

Comment: does the issue persist after caches invalidation (**File> invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart**)? also, do you have any tools (prettier, linters,etc.) watching for changes in your file and altering it?

Comment: No, cache invalidation & restart does not fix the issue. It has started working sporadically but then mostly stops working.

Comment: What has been helpful though, is upgrading just now to the newest WebStorm 2023.1.1